# Postfix mail sent to SPAM in Yahoo and Outlook (SPF, DKIM, DMARC also configured)

Tags: postfix, spam, email-server

I have implemented DMARC in out email server and got the response from some of the email domains as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<feedback>  
  <report_metadata> 
    <org_name>Yahoo! Inc.</org_name>    
    <email>postmaster@dmarc.yahoo.com</email>   
    <report_id>1422758871.723265</report_id>    
    <date_range>    
      <begin>1422662400</begin> 
      <end>1422748799 </end>    
    </date_range>   
  </report_metadata>    
  <policy_published>    
    <domain>subdomain.domain.com</domain>   
    <adkim>r</adkim>    
    <aspf>r</aspf>  
    <p>none</p> 
    <pct>100</pct>  
  </policy_published>   
  <record>  
    <row>   
      <source_ip>11.22.33.44</source_ip>    
      <count>2</count>  
      <policy_evaluated>    
        <disposition>none</disposition> 
        <dkim>pass</dkim>   
        <spf>pass</spf> 
      </policy_evaluated>   
    </row>  
    <identifiers>   
      <header_from>subdomain.domain.com</header_from>   
    </identifiers>  
    <auth_results>  
      <dkim>    
        <domain>subdomain.domain.com</domain>   
        <result>pass</result>   
      </dkim>   
      <spf> 
        <domain>subdomain.domain.com</domain>   
        <result>pass</result>   
      </spf>    
    </auth_results> 
  </record> 
</feedback>
```

As per the metadata, SPF and DKIM is validated properly. Are there any other details to be cared about from the above results?

After this implementation also, mails from our email server are sent to the SPAM folder in Outlook and Yahoo. Is there any other ways to handle this SPAM case?

Comment: Hi Aravind. Looks like your question was migrated from SuperUser. Did this question was linked with your previous question [Postfix SMTP mail is sent to SPAM](http://serverfault.com/questions/663506/postfix-smtp-mail-is-sent-to-spam) ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the domain with [MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com) and perhaps [intoDNS](http://www.intodns.com) tools? It could be that you do not have a proper PTR record (reverse DNS record) connected to the sending server IP address/domain. As explained [on this site](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/spry_menu/ptr-record/):

> Reverse DNS is setup very similar to how normal (forward) DNS is
>   setup.  When you delegate forward DNS the owner of the domain tell the
>   registrar to have your domain use certain name servers.  Reverse DNS
>   works the same way in that the owner of the IPs needs to delegate the
>   reverse DNS to DNS Made Easy name servers as well.  The owner of the
>   IPs is usually the ISP, the hosting provider, or your own group of
>   they are directly delegated from ARIN.

Which basically means, if the server sending mail has an IP address of `11.22.33.44` and the mail claims it is from the domain `subdomain.domain.com` then a PTR record should be set on the ISP’s side that connects `11.22.33.44` to `subdomain.domain.com`.

To manually check the PTR record for an IP address you can run the following [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) command from the command line; using Google’s DNS at `8.8.8.8` as an example:

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8
```

The output would be something like this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25644
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.      IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  PTR google-public-dns-a.google.com.

;; Query time: 98 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb  2 01:47:23 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 82
```

Note the “ANSWER SECTION:” that shows `google-public-dns-a.google.com.` as the PTR record connected to `8.8.8.8`. Or to just cut to the chase, just use the `+short` option like this:

```
dig -x 8.8.8.8 +short
```

And the output of that command should be something like this:

```
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the reverse DNS as well as pointer record. Both are fine. As i am using multiple subdomain in the same server, I use to have multiple pointer record for the IP address. Is that correct or it has to be modified.